# Slowly decreasing function that vanishes at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

I came across a theorem that was formulated for $\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for $1\leq p <\infty$ and $\mathrm{C}_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$, where the latter is the space of continuous functions that vanish at infinity. I wonder whether there is a continuous function that vanishes at infinity but is in no $\mathrm{L}^p$ despite for $p=\infty$. I know constructions that yield functions which are exactly in one $\mathrm{L}^p$, but those are not continuous.

It would be sufficient to find a function that decreases, but slower than any polynomial, i.e. for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$ there is some $C>0$ such that $|f(x)| \geq C (1+|x|)^{-k}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like $f(x)=\frac{1}{\log(2+|x|)}$.

Answer (score 0):

For $3\leq n\in \mathbb N$ let $f(n)=f(-n)=n^{-1/\ln \ln n}$ and let $f(x)$ be linear for $|x|\in [n,n+1]....$ Let $f(x)=f(3)$ for $|x|<3.$

For $v\in \mathbb R^k$ let $g(v)=f(\|v\|).$